# How to do the following in SQL, access?

Tags: c#, sql, ms-access

I have the following query

```
SELECT dictionaryEncryptedIndex, filelocation FROM  `DictionaryTable`
 WHERE  `dictionaryEncryptedWord` LIKE '0x0E6E'";
```

In c# I loop over the results from the above query and for every loop iteration I use the following query to get my end results:

```
SELECT * FROM  `MaskedIndexTable` 
 WHERE  `maskedIndexEncryptedIndex`
  LIKE '" + dictionaryEncryptedIndexFROMABOVEQUERY + "'
   AND `fileLocation` = '" + filelocationFROMABOVEQUERY + "'";
```

The relation between dictionaryEncryptedIndex and maskedIndexEncryptedIndex is not a one on one relation.

Does anyone know how to do the above in one SQL query that can be used in Microsoft Access?

I've tried multiple things like:

```
SELECT  * from DictionaryTable, MaskedIndexTable
  WHERE MaskedIndexTable.maskedIndexEncryptedIndex = DictionaryTable.dictionaryEncryptedIndex 
    AND  MaskedIndexTable.fileLocation =DictionaryTable.fileLocation
    AND `dictionaryEncryptedWord` LIKE '0x0E6E' 


SELECT dictionaryEncryptedWord, DictionaryTable.filelocation
  FROM DictionaryTable
 INNER JOIN MaskedIndexTable
    ON (MaskedIndexTable.maskedIndexEncryptedIndex =DictionaryTable.dictionaryEncryptedIndex  )
 WHERE  `dictionaryEncryptedWord` LIKE '...' 


SELECT distinct *
  FROM MaskedIndexTable
 INNER JOIN DictionaryTable 
    ON (MaskedIndexTable.maskedIndexEncryptedIndex = DictionaryTable.dictionaryEncryptedIndex  )
 WHERE   MaskedIndexTable.Id IN  
(
    SELECT DictionaryTable.Id
      FROM  DictionaryTable
     WHERE  `dictionaryEncryptedWord` LIKE '..') 
   AND  `dictionaryEncryptedWord` LIKE '...'
```

but none of them seem to produce the correct results (the results I get with my c# code)

Comment: it seems to me none of queries above will work.

Comment: There is no wildcard in your LIKE criteria, is this correct?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to change this if you want to use a wildcard in your LIKE criteria.

First create a query in Access similar to your first one called `encryptedWordsQuery`

```
SELECT DictionaryTable.dictionaryEncryptedIndex, DictionaryTable.fileLocation
FROM DictionaryTable
WHERE (((DictionaryTable.dictionaryEncryptedWord) Like "0x0E6E"));
```

Second create a query in Access as follows:

```
SELECT MaskedIndexTable.maskedIndex, MaskedIndexTable.maskedIndexEncryptedIndex, MaskedIndexTable.fileLocation
FROM MaskedIndexTable
WHERE Exists (SELECT * 
                FROM encryptedWordsQuery 
               WHERE MaskedIndexTable.maskedIndexEncryptedIndex = encryptedWordsQuery.dictionaryEncryptedIndex
                     AND MaskedIndexTable.fileLocation = encryptedWordsQuery.FileLocation);
```

I find it easier to create two separate queries rather than just one in Access.

Answer (score 0):

I think this should work--if you are able to post sample data we could make a SQLFiddle to demo it.

```
SELECT  dt.dictionaryEncryptedIndex, dt.filelocation 
FROM    DictionaryTable dt
    INNER JOIN MaskedIndexTable mit
        ON mit.fileLocation = dt.fileLocation 
            AND mit.maskedIndexEncryptedIndex = dt.dictionaryEncryptedIndex
WHERE   dt.dictionaryEncryptedWord LIKE '0x0E6E*'
```